# php form action and jquery validation executing at once

Tags: php, jquery

My jquery validation and php form are both executing at once, means the validations errors are  showing and also the php action is executed. here is the complete code. The jquery form submit function is returning false if the there are errors in form but even thought the form getting executed..

```
    <form class="form-3 form-horizontal ajxfrm " id="step-three" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $html->addLink(array('controller'=>'homes','action'=>'step_three')); ?>" method="post" target="_parent">
    <div id="calendar">



        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">Name<span>*</span></div>
        <div class="controls"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            <span id="nameInfo"></span></div>
        </div>


        <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">Email<span>*</span></div>
        <div class="controls"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            <span id="emailInfo"></span></div>
        </div>


        <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">Contact<span>*</span></div>
        <div class="controls"><input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" />
            <span id="contactInfo"></span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">Skype Id<span>*</span></div>
        <div class="controls"><input type="text" name="skypeid" id="skype" />
            <span id="skypeInfo"></span></div>
        </div>

        <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">Files<br/><span style="font-size:10px; font-style:italic">(Optional)</span></div>
        <div class="controls">
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload[]" multiple/>
            <span id="fileInfo"></span><br/>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
        <div class="control-label">Your Message<span>*</span></div>
        <div class="controls"><textarea rows="3" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            <span id="messageInfo"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="submit" style=" text-align:right;">        
         <input type="hidden" name="post" value="1"/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Next" id="step3submit" style="margin-right:-20%; margin-top:5%"/> 
    </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the jquery file

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       //global vars
       var form = $("#step-three");
       var name = $("#name");
       var nameInfo = $("#nameInfo");
       var email = $("#email");
       var emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");
       var contact = $("#contact");
       var contactInfo = $("#contactInfo");
       var skype = $("#skype");
       var skypeInfo = $("#skypeInfo");
       var message = $("#message");

       //On blur
       name.blur(validateName);
       email.blur(validateEmail);
       contact.blur(validateContact);
       skype.blur(validateSkype);
       message.blur(validateMessage);
       //On key press
       name.keyup(validateName);
       email.keyup(validateEmail);
       contact.keyup(validateContact);
       skype.keyup(validateSkype);
       message.keyup(validateMessage);
       //On Submitting
       form.submit(function () {
           if (validateName() & validateEmail() & validateContact() & validateSkype() & validateMessage())
               return true;
           else
               return false;
       });

       //validation functions

       function validateEmail() {
           //testing regular expression
           var a = $("#email").val();
           var filter = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
           //if it's valid email
           if (email.val().length == 0) {
               email.addClass("error");
               emailInfo.text("Required");
               emailInfo.addClass("error");
               return false;
           } else if (filter.test(a)) {
               email.removeClass("error");
               emailInfo.text("");
               emailInfo.removeClass("error");
               return true;
           }
           //if it's NOT valid
           else if (!filter.test(a)) {
               email.addClass("error");
               emailInfo.text("Valid Email Please");
               emailInfo.addClass("error");
               return false;
           }
       }

       function validateName() {
           //if it's NOT valid
           if (name.val().length == 0) {
               name.addClass("error");
               nameInfo.text("Required");
               nameInfo.addClass("error");
               return false;
           }
           //if it's valid
           else {
               name.removeClass("error");
               nameInfo.text("");
               nameInfo.removeClass("error");
               return true;
           }
       }

       function validateContact() {
           //if it's NOT valid
           if (contact.val().length == 0) {
               contact.addClass("error");
               contactInfo.text("Required");
               contactInfo.addClass("error");
               return false;
           }
           //if it's valid
           else {
               contact.removeClass("error");
               contactInfo.text("");
               contactInfo.removeClass("error");
               return true;
           }
       }

       function validateSkype() {
           //if it's NOT valid
           if (skype.val().length == 0) {
               skype.addClass("error");
               skypeInfo.text("Required");
               skypeInfo.addClass("error");
               return false;
           }
           //if it's valid
           else {
               skype.removeClass("error");
               skypeInfo.text("");
               skypeInfo.removeClass("error");
               return true;
           }
       }
       /*  function validatePass1(){
    var a = $("#password1");
    var b = $("#password2");

    //it's NOT valid
    if(pass1.val().length <5){
        pass1.addClass("error");
             pass1Info.text("Ey! Remember: At least 5 characters: letters, numbers and '_'");
        pass1Info.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //it's valid
    else{           
        pass1.removeClass("error");
        pass1Info.text("At least 5 characters: letters, numbers and '_'");
        pass1Info.removeClass("error");
        validatePass2();
        return true;
    }
}
function validatePass2(){
    var a = $("#password1");
    var b = $("#password2");
    //are NOT valid
    if( pass1.val() != pass2.val() ){
        pass2.addClass("error");
        pass2Info.text("Passwords doesn't match!");
        pass2Info.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //are valid
    else{
        pass2.removeClass("error");
        pass2Info.text("Confirm password");
        pass2Info.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
}*/

       function validateMessage() {
           //it's NOT valid
           if (message.val().length < 10) {
               message.addClass("error");
               messageInfo.text("More than 10 Characters required");
               messageInfo.addClass("error");
               return false;
           }
           if (message.val().length == 0) {
               message.addClass("error");
               messageInfo.text("Required");
               messageInfo.addClass("error");
               return false;
           }
           //it's valid
           else {
               message.removeClass("error");
               messageInfo.text("");
               messageInfo.removeClass("error");
               return true;
           }
       }
   });
```

Comment: You need to use logical AND operator (&&) instead of Bitwise AND operator (&).REF:http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fbitande.htm

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `preventDefault()` function. The submit function can't be 'canceled' with returning false. it is an event and there are many handlers 'listening' to it. You have to stop the event from propagating, thus preventing the handlers to handle the event ;)
The code:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    if(!(validateName() && validateEmail() && validateContact() && validateSkype() && validateMessage())){
        e.preventDefault();
        // and maybe some alert() with fail info
    }
    else{
        //whatever you need if validation suceeds
    }
});
```

Comment: Try using `$("#step-three").submit` instead of `$("form").submit`.

Answer (score 0):

use `&&` place of `&`
I hope it will help

Comment: `&&` and `&` are very similar in most of programing languages (I think that it counts for js too). The main difference is that the `&&` operator stops checking the other conditions if there is one fail, while the `&` will execute next conditions even though there was a `false` already.

Comment: this is working but the validation error is showing one by one but not at once if i submit without giving any inputs

Comment: return false; removed from function

Comment: @KamilT No. `&` is bitwise AND, which works on two integers and returns another one with bits set that were set in *both* of the inputs: `0x1C03 & 0x3603 == 0x1403`.

Comment: @michaelb958 - you're right, but it only works that way in only in assignment. Inside `if` statement it's a logical operator, try `if(2==2 & 1==1){console.log('true')}`. When you test something, you get a bool value as result. In the end, if you use single ampersand to binary `AND` bool values, you will end up with a bool value - that way you can use it in if statement. It's not a good practice, but still - you CAN use it that way ;)

Comment: @KamilT This is only the case due to boolean-to-integer rules inherited from C; and why would you need to do that, anyway?

Comment: As I said before - using a single `&` to check logical values is not a good practice (it's quite silly way ihmo), but still - it will work, thus it isn't the reason why OP's code doesn't work ;) I've came around a few projects where using `&` in `if` statement was used in a smart way, so I just wanted to point out that it is possible.

Comment: @michaelb958: imagine that you have two functions, both of them return a boolean and you have to call both of them, before you do something. If they both return `true`, then you do some extra actions, but you still NEED to call BOTH of them. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daUMy/3/   using the `&` may not be the best way, but here it works as it should.

Comment: @KamilT You do have a point there; however, there are doubtless clearer ways to do that.